# How to detect if a video is playing on android platform?

Tags: android, video, frameworks, surfaceflinger

Is there  some api or method to know if some video is playing on android platform?

I want to stop some background job when a video is playing at foreground.

The api or method had better comes from surfaceflinger, window manager service etc. framework modules.

Thanks.

Comment: is the video in your own app or another app?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic   another  app， and I can modify framework code add new interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SurfaceFlinger process can know that it is receiving frames at a consistent rate, but it can't know if it's a video or just app animation.

The mediaserver process is responsible for managing the hardware video decoders.  It can know if a video is being decoded, but it can't know if the video is being displayed.  It won't be involved if the app is using a custom software-only decoder.

There isn't an unequivocal way to detect that a video is being played and presented on the display.